# Load Spritekit scene from a subclass

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a subclass of SKScene where I want to load a scene from a `.sks` File. I have to use `super.init(size: CGSize)` to initialize the SKScene in the init of my subclass instead of `super.init(fileNamed: String)`, because `super.init(fileNamed: String)` ist not a designated initializer. How can I subclass SKScene and with the semantic of `super.init(fileNamed: String)` to load a scene from a file?

```
import SpriteKit

class Spielfeld: SKScene {

    var x: Int     // Anzahl Felder in x-Richtung
    var y: Int     // Anzahl Felder in y-Richtung
    var up: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    var down: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    var left: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    var right: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()

    init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int, fileNamed: String, size: CGSize) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        super.init(size: size)
        up = self.childNode(withName: "Up") as! SKSpriteNode
        down = self.childNode(withName: "Down") as! SKSpriteNode
        left = self.childNode(withName: "Left") as! SKSpriteNode
        right = self.childNode(withName: "Right") as! SKSpriteNode
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: If it's loaded from a `.sks` file, you should implement `init?(coder:)`

Comment: you mean the `init?(coder:)` at the bottom of my code? how do I use it to have the same init as in the init above?

Comment: how do I implement it, that i can initialize the subclass of SKScene like in `super.init(fileNamed:)`?

Comment: My bad, you don't need `init?(coder:)` if you're using `init(fileNamed:)`. I'm glad somebody helped you better than I did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary as in .sks there is a custom class. You just put "Spielfeld" inside.

Then in viewController:

```
if let sceneNode = SKScene.init(fileNamed: "Spielfeld(Whatever your name is here)") { 
         (sceneNode as! Spielfeld).property = "anyValueToUse"

         if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            view.presentScene(sceneNode) //present the scene.
   }
```

If you decided to load from a file, there is no reason to init again. You may add init functions by overriding the following:

```
   override func sceneDidLoad() {  
     } //called after .sks is loaded.

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
//change the size here.
 } // called after presentation.
```

Comment: With `.property` you mean the attributes `x, y, ...` from my subclass, right? Also when I set those attributes like in your example, in which object they will me stored when I do `(sceneNode as! Spielfeld)`? Isn't it necessary to store `(sceneNode as! Spielfeld) in a variable before?

Comment: Not necessarily. This example is just showing you another place where you can set values before presenting.